# I wonder how to make simple query like this in Cosmos Db: SELECT c.pk as pk1, * FROM c

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I wonder if it's possible to select a field under some alias and all the rest fields in a single query.

This query works:
`SELECT * FROM c`

and this query works:
`SELECT c.pk as pk1 FROM c`

But this one does not:
`SELECT c.pk as pk1, * FROM c`

Error: "One of the input values is invalid."

The expected result is same field 'pk' appears twice in the output: as 'pk' and 'pk1'. It's needed to circumvent current limitation of Azure Data Factory to prevent mapping the same field twice in "Copy Data" activity.

I need "all the rest" without listing them all, so with new fields added I do not have to update the query.

Comment: Can you try `SELECT c.pk as pk1, c.* FROM c`?

Comment: Well, I did and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding within   `[]`

```
SELECT ["c.id"] as pk1, ["c.*"] FROM c
```

Comment: It returns this result, the fields seemed to get treated like string constants: [
{ 
"pk1": [ "c.pk" ], 
"$1": [ "c.*"] 
} ...
]}

Comment: and if I run it without quotes `SELECT [c.pk] as pk1, [c.*] FROM c` then same error shows up

Comment: unfortunately it does not work. please check my first comment to see what comes out with quotes